# Amazon Alexa Skill - how to get user id of the MAIN amazon account (not the ".ask")

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

Getting "some" user id in the AWS Lambda handling my alexa skill is very easy, just do this in handler

`user_id = ask_utils.request_util.get_user_id(handler_input)`

However, user ids that are available in the input are different ones then the ones for the main Amazon account, resp. the one returned by "Login with Amazon" (LWA) flow e.g.

**Alexa Skill "userId":** `amzn1.ask.account.YAQMPHVKPI76M5XI7EWFDDU6......`

**Login with amazon "user_id":** `amzn1.account.PXTLBJMX2B74D2......`

As you can see they don't only have a different prefixes, they are also *completely different*. However I already have login with amazon ready in the application and I just want to connect data that are coming from the Alexa with the particular user.

Is there a way how to get

**A) The "main" amazon account id from the alexa skill (python lambda)?**

or
B) the "ask.amazon" id from the "main" amazon account OAuth flow?

Comment: Did you implement account linking with LWA in your Alexa Skill? If so, you should have `accessToken` in the user request, which you can use to retrieve the LWA user_id.

Comment: @Christina that would however require user to connect from my app to amazon and then from skill to amazon and that of course would work, but there would be 1 more unnecessary step :/

Comment: So are you trying to link the user between your app and the skill? I don't think it's possible without some sort of account linking. To my knowledge, there's not a way to convert Alexa Skill `userId` to LWA `user_id` or vise versa. Also note that the Alexa Skill `userId` changes each time you disable/enable the skill.

Comment: @Christina You're right, doesn't seem to be possible without linking, however - I found a solution for my case - it's the "App-to-App" linking - it's done **through the LWA**,  you just have to **add the `alexa::skills:account_linking` scope**, then you can use the `Alexa Skill Activation API` and the `enablement` endpoint to enable the skill and link the account programatically :)

Comment: that's great, glad to hear~

Comment: @Christina except it appears, for some reason Amazon is currently not supporting `profile` scope and this `scope` `alexa::skills:account_linking` - even though they're documented here: https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/account-linking/app-to-app-account-linking-starting-from-your-app.html#urls-and-endpoints
and here https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/account-linking/skill-activation-api.html#prerequisites

Comment: I think your use case fall under their FAQ "Q: What if my skill requires permissions? Can I get these during app-to-app account linking?" Unless you need the user's Amazon email & name, you can try requesting for `profile:user_id` scope instead of `profile`, which doesn't require user consent.

Comment: @Christina Yes that's what I did but it only works for regular LWA, not for linking (also it doesn't solve the auto-enable&link problem either). Can you provide a link to that FAQ you've mentioned please ? :) thank you

Comment: The FAQ I referenced is actually in the first link you shared above :P
[link](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/account-linking/app-to-app-account-linking-starting-from-your-app.html#faq)